# ToString vs. ToString() in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

What is the difference between using ToString and ToString() in VB.NET?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Nothing.  VB.NET allows you exclude the parentheses on any method that doesn't take in an argument.

Comment: Exactly the right answer, good practice would be to go ahead and get used to those parentheses and add them in, as if you do any cross language development in .Net (pretty common for anyone using VB.Net) it is easier not to forget them if you already use them.

Comment: Agreed, VB.net allows you to be pretty lazy and not use best practices.  Im not sure if the omission of parans is valid if option strict is set?

Comment: I sometimes wish I could do that In C#. I find empty parentheses annoying.

Comment: Empty parenthases are there for a reason!  It let's you know the differance between a property (or public feild) and a method on the class.

Comment: The D programming language lets you omit parentheses, and goes one step further in that it lets you assign to functions taking one parameter: a = 10; is a(10);

Comment: @Charles. That's silly, it doesn't matter if it is a property or method when you are reading it.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answer is wholly correct but does not cover when ToString is used as a Method.  This is essentially incorrect coding but it is possible

```
Dim sbrBuilder as New StringBuilder

...

sbrBuilder.ToString()
return sbrBuilder.ToString
```

The first ToString (which does nothing) does not produce an error but the brackets are forced on by the IDE.  The second ToString does not require brackets (optional - as explained already in the Answer) as it is used to collect the value of ToString.

Hopefully this will help anyone who is wondering why the IDE keeps adding brackets on ToString - then you will realise that you forgot to assign it to anything like I did