# Need help with Eval inside DataList

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

This should be simple enough, and I blame this primarily on my inexperience working with DataLists, Repeaters, etc.

I have a DataList control which I am using to display the items in a shopping cart. Everything is going along fine with my binding of the different controls using Eval("ColumnName") until I get to the price column.

My goal is to render it like so:

> ### Total Item Cost
>
> $20.00 
>   ($5.00 each)

I am trying to accomplish this with two ASP Label controls inside the table cell:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTotalItemCost" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TotalItemCost") %>'>
</asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='(<%# Eval("Price")%> each)' >
</asp:Label>
```

Unfortunately it is rendering out the column as:

> ### Total Item Cost
>
> $20.00 
>   (<%# Eval("Price")%> each)

I've tried a couple other methods, but they end up giving me "server tag not well formed" errors. I am pretty sure this should be simple but I'm stumped at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Text='<%#"(" + Eval("Price").ToString() + " each)"%>'
```

Comment: Option Strict On prohibits operands of type Object for operator '+'. That's closer than what I had before (thanks to the double quotes, which I had screwed up).

Comment: I just added .ToString to the Eval("Price") and now it works. Thanks a lot Ahmad.

Comment: I thought ToString is a method call so would be ToString(), since you are dealing with monetary ammounts you can add a string format say ToString('0.##') to get the formatting.

Comment: Dave you're right. In C# calling it as ToString would cause the compiler to complain. However, this is not the case in VB.NET where using ToString and ToString() are both acceptable, although probably confusing to C# devs at first. In fact, here's a more complete answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390648/tostring-vs-tostring-in-vb-net

Comment: Good catch on that Ahmad (you too Dave). I'll edit the answer again to reflect the more friendly version.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a format string? I know this works in C#, haven't tested it in VB.NET

```
<asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price", "({0} each)"%>' />
```