# asp:DataList control with asp:LinkButton inside - something's weird

Tags: asp.net

I'm working through examples in a book trying to learn ASP.NET, and I've stumbled on something strange in there. First of all, if I type it as it's written in the book, VS gives me errors. This is the code as it's written in the book:

```
    <asp:DataList ID="employeesList" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="extraDetailsLiteral" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />
        Name: <strong><%#Eval("Name") %></strong><br />
        Username: <strong><%#Eval("Username") %></strong><br />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="detailsButton" runat="server" Text=<%#"View more details about " + Eval("Name")%> 
            CommandName="MoreDetailsPlease" 
            CommandArgument=<%#Eval("EmployeeID")%> />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        <hr />
    </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

So, I've plucked at it for a while, and came up with this solution which actually compiles:

```
    <asp:DataList ID="employeesList" runat="server" onitemcommand="employeesList_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="extraDetailsLiteral" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />
        Name: <strong><%#Eval("Name") %></strong><br />
        Username: <strong><%#Eval("Username") %></strong><br />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="detailsButton" runat="server" Text='View more details about <%# Eval("Name") %>' 
            CommandName="MoreDetailsPlease" CommandArgument='<%Eval("EmployeeID") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        <hr />
    </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Notice that I've also added the OnItemCommand in the asp:DataList tag, so now I'm able to fire the event as expected.

However, results in the browser isn't what I expect; the Name and Username listed in **strong text** show just fine, but the Literal control that should show extra details (the EmployeeID field) and the Name field inside the LinkButton won't show their values in the page:

[not showing as expected http://lh6.ggpht.com/_x84bQLYH57A/SgxzygartcI/AAAAAAAAAIY/nhT-6RUJa6o/s144/EmployeeDirectory_notshowing.jpg](http://lh6.ggpht.com/_x84bQLYH57A/SgxzygartcI/AAAAAAAAAIY/nhT-6RUJa6o/s144/EmployeeDirectory_notshowing.jpg)

It **should** say "EmployeeID: 1" and "View more details about Zak Ruvalcaba"

I guess it's the Eval function that's not working when inside another control, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the LinkButton as :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="detailsButton" runat="server" 
     Text='<%# Eval("Name", "View more details about {0}") %>' 
     CommandName="MoreDetailsPlease" 
     CommandArgument='<%# Eval("EmployeeID") %>' />
```

Sorry I confused the order of parameters. I updated my answer. Format must be the second parameter.

Comment: This solution causes the application to crash, saying DataBinding: 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' does not contain a property with the name 'View more details about {0}'.

Could you look at it again? I hope this is the way to do it, as it seems fairly elegant. :)

Comment: Half-a-point for spotting the missing # in the CommandArgument.. ;)

Comment: I'm giving your updated solution the answer as it's IMHO the more elegant one. But TheTXI has an interesting take on it too, so I upvoted him. Hope I'm doing this correctly, I'm new to SO! Thanks guys, for your replies!

Comment: @tplive  : Wellcome to SO ! Yes upvotes courage people to give good answers. TheTXI's answer is simpler one. But I like this one, because formatting currencies dates and decimals is easier in this one :)

Answer (score 1):

You can view another question I posted yesterday concerning something eerily similar here:

[Need help with Eval inside DataList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853299/need-help-with-eval-inside-datalist)

I do believe Canavar actually gave the correct answer, however.

Comment: Your link was interesting, I had no idea the return from Eval was an Object, but when I applied your solution, like this:

Text='<%#"View more details about " + Eval("Name").ToString() + " "%>' it works like a charm!

Comment: tplive: feel free to vote me up (and maybe my original question as well) if it helped :)